# Python - How to determine if only certain letters are in a string?

Tags: python, string, list

How can we determine if a string only consists of `'A'` `'B'` or `'C'`?
For example if the word is `'ABCBABCBABCBCABCA'`, then it is fine, or produces `True`.
But if the word was `'ABCABC%'` then it would `return` `False`?

Comment: Do all permitted characters need to appear?  Should `"ACAC"` give `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 4):

Python makes this really easy with [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-set):

```
>>> def validate(my_string, ok='ABC'):
...     return set(my_string) <= set(ok)
...

>>> s = 'ABCBABCBABCBCABCA'
>>> validate(s)
True
>>> s2 = 'ABCABC%'
>>> validate(s2)
False
>>> s3 = 'ABBA'
>>> validate(s3)
True
```

*Note:* If you want it to `return` `False` if not all of the whitelisted characters are used, simply change the `<=` to `==`.

Comment: What if the word is `"ABBA"`?

Comment: Whether you want `==` or `<=` depends upon whether the OP demands that each character appear.  I've asked the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [10]: def isChars(s, chars):
   ....:     if all(char in set(chars) for char in s):
   ....:         return True
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return False
   ....:     

In [11]: s = "ABCBABCBABCBCABCA"

In [12]: isChars(s, "ABC")
Out[12]: True

In [13]: s = "ABCBABCBABCBCABCA%"

In [14]: isChars(s, "ABC")
Out[14]: False
```

Of course, as@larsga points out, you could reduce `isChars` to a one line function:

```
def isChars(s, chars):
    return all(char in set(chars) for char in s)
```

This is effectively what @jonsharpe has done

Comment: Your isChars should be one line: return set(s) == set(chars) (it should also be named is_chars to be properly pythonic)

Comment: @larsga: True. I was trying to be more explicit, as I figured it would help OP more

Comment: You've fallen victim to one of the classic list comprehension bugs. `set(chars)` is recomputed every iteration. It *probably* won't have a major performance impact, but who knows? Maybe in the future, `chars` will be a significant portion of the Unicode codespace.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern="^[ABC]+$"
>>> s1="ABCBABCBABCBCABCA"
>>> s2="ABCABC%"
>>> re.match(pattern,s1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10d75f7e8>
>>> re.match(pattern,s2)
>>>
```

Wrapping this in a function to return true or false is trivial.  Learning regex for string matching is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest approach is:

```
def check(word, chars):
    """Check that a word only contains chars."""
    return all(c in chars for c in word)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
all_abc = not your_text.translate(None, 'ABC')
```